IMultiLingualEntity and IEntityTranslation
I was using ASP.NET Boilerplate (ABP) and recently decided to migrate my project to the new ABP Framework. In ASP.NET Boilerplate, I was using the interfaces IMultiLingualEntity and IEntityTranslation to support translations.
However, it seems that the new ABP Framework doesn't support these interfaces. Is there another way to implement multi-language support in the new ABP Framework?
Thank you!
I found this article which might be helpful
https://abp.io/community/articles/how-to-design-multilingual-entity-8glnk6vu
your text
